# crackLib similar functionality for GWT

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt

i need to test a given password for its strength, similar to how crackLib works. To make sure that the password cannot be easily guessed.

1) How can i do this check in GWT ui itself instead of going backend

2) Would checking to ensure no dictionary words are there in the password a reasonable substitution, if so how can this be done??

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting your password checking code in javascript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be done on client side as there is few safe ways of doing this. Anyway you try to pass a candidate to a GWT implementation of crackLib in browser exposes it to be hacked or leak the passwords nature.

Your best bet is to send it over RPC with XSRF enabled and verify it over server.

Surely a small roundtrip to the server to ensure safety is small price.